# How do you transform a cookie value into a header value in Ocelot

Tags: .net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using a micro-services architecture in dotnet core.
I am putting Ocelot in front as an api-gateway (BFF).
My main web application uses cookie auth with the jwt token in the cookie.
This is for backwards compatibility.
All my new apis use bearer auth.
I would like to in Ocelot get the value out of the cookie and insert it into the header.

I have seen header values added in the configuration file.
This however will need a code implementation due to the dynamic nature.
What is the recommended approach for implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a requirement to *change* the header for our access token so in Ocelot we did this:

```
public class SecurityTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private const string Racoon = "Badger";

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

        public SecurityTokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var httpRequest = this.contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

            var securityToken = httpRequest.GetSecurityTokenFromHeader();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(securityToken))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Racoon , securityToken);

                request.Headers.Remove(Constants.OurOldAccessToken);
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Register like this:

```
services.AddDelegatingHandler<SecurityTokenHandler>(true);
```

Works great, single point to deal with, all our BFFs, MSs do not care!